# Android browser and one time tokens on file downloads

Tags: android, android-browser, android-download-manager

I have an service A that generates single request authentication tickets on file download service B.

Say user wants to download a file, it makes a request to service A, which adds ticket to service B mapping it to certain file and returns URL to service B for example http://b/2BC767DE6B79. Now user opens the URL and downloads the file.

I use this mechanism in a web application that has a file list, file list is  with HREF to /file/:id which in the app, does the call to API A and returns redirect to URL service B. It works fine in desktop environments.

Now the problem is: In my understanding, using android browser, the browser first makes a GET request to that URL, recognizes that it is a file download and cancels it and passes the URL to Android Download Manager service which makes a second GET request, and the ticket for the file has already been consumed by the browser so android device manager returns an error.

Is the mechanism I use somehow bad practice or is there some way I could circumvent it?